# Scale canvas drawing to size of the screen

Tags: android, canvas

I have custom view (basically drawing a line chart). I want it to fit layout by width and height. For instance, this is what I have now (without scaling):

[image]

While I want the left side of the screen correspond with xMin (plus offset maybe) and right side of the screen correspond to xMax (despite how small or big the chart is). The same is for the height. Visually, I'm trying to achieve following result (ignore purple rect):
[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // make left bottom (0,0)
    canvas.translate(0, canvas.getHeight());
    canvas.scale(canvas.getWidth()/(getMaxX()-getMinX()), 
               -canvas.getHeight()/(getMaxY()-getMinY()));

    canvas.drawLines(values, paint);
}
```

With this scaling I got following:

[image]

I have no idea of how to scale to fit the screen

Comment: Is it possible that it has something to do with onMeasur()?

Comment: Ok, the problem seems to be about casting division to int producing infelicity. Added explicit casting ``(float)`` to parameters in scale method. I'll keep question open for a while, so someone maybe can point to another issues in my code.

Comment: Please give more source code also how you setup canvas width/height ?!

Comment: @NikolaLukic I don't setup width/height, I just invoke canvas.getWidth() (same for height).